# Nativescript Vue @tap crashes on Android 6.0 but not Android 8.0 NoSuchFieldError

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I was able to run the app just fine and make all of the selections without crashes on Android 8.0 emulator.

On Android 6.0 emulator, When I select either Airport or Runway menu in this photo, it crashes  while others didn't (especially aircraft menu have same code as those two menus)
Screenshot of menus

[image: Screenshot of menus]

In App.vue  there's a part of xml code for first two (including aircraft -keep in mind..aircraft menu works)

```
 <CardView col="0" row="0" class="cardStyle" elevation="40" radius="10">
                      <StackLayout  class="cardContent"  > 
                        <Label  text="Airport Name:"/>
                        <TextField  :text="SelectedAirportName" hint="Tap to Select" editable="false"  @tap="onCustomArprtTap" />
                      </StackLayout>
                    </CardView>

                <CardView col="1" row="0"   class="cardStyle" elevation="40" radius="10">
                  <StackLayout  class="cardContent">
                    <Label text="Heading:"/>
                    <TextField :isEnabled="AirportSelected" :text="SelectedRunway" hint="Tap to Select" editable="false" @tap="onCustomHeadingTap" />
                  </StackLayout>
                </CardView>

                <CardView col="0" row="1" colSpan="2" class="cardStyle" elevation="40" radius="10">
                  <StackLayout class="cardContent"> 
                    <Label textWrap="true" text="Aircraft:"/>
                     <TextField :text="SelectedAircraftLine" hint="Tap to Select" editable="false" @tap="onCustomArcrftTap"/>
                  </StackLayout>
                </CardView>
```

The link to creating airport modal is [AirportList.vue](https://github.com/stahlie/first-ns-app/blob/master/app/components/AirportList.vue)

and the link to creating runway modal is [RunwayList.vue](https://github.com/stahlie/first-ns-app/blob/master/app/components/RunwayList.vue)

and the link to (working) aircraft modal is [AircraftList.vue](https://github.com/stahlie/first-ns-app/blob/master/app/components/RunwayList.vue)

and When I click on Airport menu in the screenshot,  I get this following error:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onSingleTapUp failed

Error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "I" field "AXIS_RELATIVE_X" in 
class "Landroid/view/MotionEvent;" or its superclasses
com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1120)
com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1000)
com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:987)
com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:967)
com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:959)
com.tns.gen.android.view.GestureDetector_SimpleOnGestureListener_vendor_65760_26_TapAndDoubleTapGestureListenerImpl.onSingleTapUp(GestureDetector_SimpleOnGestureListener_vendor_65760_26_TapAndDoubleTapGestureListenerImpl.java:17)
android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:635)
android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat$GestureDetectorCompatImplJellybeanMr2.onTouchEvent(GestureDetectorCompat.java:480)
android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(GestureDetectorCompat.java:543)
com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1120)
com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1000)
com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:987)
com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:967)
com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:959)
com.tns.gen.java.lang.Object_vendor_59746_26_TouchListenerImpl.onTouch(Object_vendor_59746_26_TouchListenerImpl.java:18)
android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9290)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2765)
android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6025)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.application/files/app/vendor.js, line: 27669, column: 16

StackTrace: 
Frame: function:'formatProperty',
```

I couldn't resolve it.  I am puzzled that it works fine on Android 8.0 emulator but not Android 6.0

Comment: Can you try commenting `ScrollView` above `ListView` on `AirportList` and `RunwayList` component, I don't think they are required. Please let's know if that makes any difference.

Comment: It still crashes..   It immediately crashed once I "click/tap" the AirportList TextField.

Comment: Does it still crash if you use a Button instead of TextField?

Comment: Interesting. It didn't crash when I use a Button...It's also interesting that Aircraft list still uses Textfield without crashing and its file with codes is similiar to Airport & Runway list...any suggestion how to make it work with input field instead of button?

Comment: I think you don't need a TextField as you are not going to edit anything there if I'm not wrong. You could style the button to look like TextField, with bottom border and text color, that should be a workaround.